# How to setup lucene index for AEM

Tags: lucene, aem, jcr

I have the following Lucene index setup on AEM running Oak 1.0.11. I would like to know if this the right way to serialize an oak index, so that it can deploy to our stage and production instance without manual CRXDE setup.

I also have the following questions about lucene index for the Oak JCR

1. The [oak docs](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/query.html) say to set the type to property. but the [abobe docs](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/queries-and-indexing.html) say to set fulltextEnabled to false for property indexes (with type lucene). I followed the adobe docs, is the type correct?
2. How does one set the direction of the Lucene Ordered property index?
3. Towards the bottom of the [lucene docs](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html) page it says that oak index can be anywhere in the JCR and will index content at or below (I'm paraphrasing). Does that work in AEM? I tried that, but it didn't seem to work at all

> *WARN* [141.211.155.95 [1429825328215] GET /content/michigan-lsa/earth/en/news-events/all-news/jcr:content/par/news_archive.story.html/1.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.property.strategy.ContentMirrorStoreStrategyTraversed 5000 nodes using index cq:template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:oak="http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/ns/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0" xmlns:st="http://www.st.com/nt/st" jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <lsaNews
        jcr:primaryType="oak:QueryIndexDefinition"
        async="async"
        compatVersion="2"
        evaluatePathRestrictions="{Boolean}true"
        reindex="{Boolean}false"
        type="lucene">
        <indexRules jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <nt:base
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                includePropertyTypes="all">
                <properties jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <featured
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        name="jcr:content/featured"
                        nodeName="featured"
                        ordered="{Boolean}true"
                        propertyIndex="{Boolean}true"
                        type="Boolean"/>
                    <releaseDate
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        name="jcr:content/releaseDate"
                        nodeName="releaseDate"
                        ordered="{Boolean}true"
                        propertyIndex="{Boolean}true"
                        type="Date"/>
                    <cqtemplate
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        name="jcr:content/cq:template"
                        propertyIndex="{Boolean}true"
                        type="String"/>
                    <cqtags
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        name="jcr:content/cq:tags"
                        nodeName="cq:tags"
                        propertyIndex="{Boolean}true"/>
                </properties>
            </nt:base>
        </indexRules>
    </lsaNews>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: A major development in getting Oak index functional, hotfix 6316, that helped a lot! https://helpx.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager/kb/aem6-available-hotfixes/_jcr_content/main-pars/download/file.res/HF%206316%20Oak%201.0.13-release%20notes.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can use Explain query tool to get more info on your query so that you can create the index on required property for your query. Please see - [Explain query tool](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/queries-and-indexing.html#ACS%20Commons%20Indexing%20Tools)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I've tried Explain Query and it gives some good information about what's going. tho, I still have the questions about lucene index on oak. #1. I think type=lucene is good, #2 does it matter?? #3 it seems in aem the indexes can only be under /oak:index/